# Ubuntu 16.04.1 Cannot login

Tags: login

I tried to delete .Xauthority, .ICEauthority, change permissions for them, tried load other DE, tried log in as a new user and guest account. Nothing works. Laptop lenovo g510, gpu radeon r7 m265
Some logs, maybe help
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLzjy.jpg  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdl8v.jpg

Comment: What happens when you try to log in?

Comment: @David Foerster just back to login screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop